# Can you order a X509Certificate2Collection to use the newest certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate2

I have a set of certificates from using the code:

```
 var set = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, name, false);
```

Since I'm finding the certificate by its subject name, and the certificate is set up to auto-renew and be downloaded/installed onto the machine automatically - there is a chance there will be two certificates with the same subject name in the store. (last parameter to returnValidOnly is false, because I think setting it to true runs into other problems of the code internally checking that the certificate chain is valid)

How does the Find method order the list of certificates returned? does set[0] always have the newest one? Is there a way I can order the certificates in this collection without writing a manual O(n^2) loop?

Answer (score 2):

> How does the Find method order the list of certificates returned?

Most likely, the order out of Find is the same order that went in.  So there's the implicit question of how the X509Store.Certificates collection is ordered. https://sysadmins.lv/retired-msft-blogs/alejacma/how-does-cryptoapi-order-the-certificates-in-the-stores.aspx suggests it's reverse-alphabetical of the hexadecimal encoding of the SHA-1 thumbprint of the certificate (which makes sense given the thumbprints show up in the registry as part of the storage model).  This means the collection is, for your purposes, unsorted.

> Is there a way I can order the certificates in this collection without writing a manual O(n^2) loop?

While sorting is expensive (though, the fastest general sorting algorithms are n log n, not n^2), selecting is not.  Finding the maximum of a collection is just an O(N) operation:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;

foreach (X509Certificate2 cur in coll)
{
    if (cert == null || cert.NotBefore < cur.NotBefore)
    {
        cert = cur;
    }
}

if (cert == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

This loop assumes that the NotBefore value is essentially the issuance time (which is almost always true) and that the newest one is what you want.